# Execute dbms_mview.refresh from CodeIgniter

Tags: oracle, package

I need to execute `EXECUTE dbms_mview.refresh('MATERIALIZED_VIEW_NAME')` calling this package from the model but when I try to do it with a statement like this one:

```
$refresh = $this->db->query('EXECUTE DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH(\'CRM_LISTADO_CONTACTOS\')');
```

But I receive a database error from this line in the model. I've also tried with `db->store_procedure` but it didn't work either.

Any clue how to call a package?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Doesn't show any error just error. Then if I typed it in the Oracle developer and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've never heard of CodeIgniter before, but my educated guess is that you're using $this->$db->query and you're *not* passing it a query?

My guess would be, if it supports calling stored procedures at all, perhaps there's a $this->$db->call_function or $this->$db->call_procedure, or something?

Sorry, this is really a Codeigniter question, not an Oracle question.

Comment: Yes, it is a CI stuff. I also tried to force it using oci_execute as follows but it still gives a ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement:

$conn = oci_connect(usr, pass, host);
$query = 'EXEC dbms_mview.refresh(\'MAT_VIEw_NAME\')';

 $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
 $r = oci_execute($stid, OCI_DEFAULT);

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like I finally managed to solve the problem. I'm posting my solution, maybe it might help someone else.

It looks like CI crashes when parsing the parameters passed to the procedure so, I had to go back to the sources and use the basic oci_execute method. My solution looks like this:

In the model:

...code that executes INSERTS and UPDATES...then...

```
    $p_name_mat_view = 'VIEW_NAME';
    $p_refresh_method = NULL;

    $conn = oci_connect('username', 'password', 'hostname');
    $query = 'BEGIN dbms_mview.refresh(:p_name_mat_view, :p_refresh_method); END;';

    $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);

    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":p_name_mat_view", & $p_name_mat_view);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":p_refresh_method", & $p_refresh_method);
    $r = oci_execute($stid);
```

And it worked!

Cheers,
Vero