# Error : ORA-01704: string literal too long

Tags: oracle, codeigniter, clob, nclob

While I try to set the value of over 4000 characters on a field that has data type `CLOB`, it gives me this error :

> ORA-01704: string literal too long.

Any suggestion, which data type would be applicable for me if I have to set value of unlimited characters although for my case, it happens to be of about `15000` chars.

Note : The long string that I am trying to store is encoded in ANSI.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

What are you using when operate with CLOB?

In all events you can do it with PL/SQL

```
DECLARE
  str varchar2(32767);
BEGIN
  str := 'Very-very-...-very-very-very-very-very-very long string value';
  update t1 set col1 = str;
END;
/
```

[Proof link on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/58895/1)

Comment: Thank you, but CI is not supporting these procedure stuffs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946641/error-this-feature-is-not-available-for-the-database-you-are-using#comment19232999_13946641

Comment: I guess you can wrap this code in a procedure and Codeigniter can execute it. Sorry but I don't have Codeigniter for checking. Look here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7930092/1910242)

Comment: Did it, but could I define that size of varchar2, check this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947222/error-ora-06553-pls-306-wrong-number-or-types-of-arguments-in-call-to-proced/13947420#13947420

Comment: Will [this info (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/fuecks-lobs-095315.html)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/fuecks-lobs-095315.html) be useful for you?

Comment: I don't know what I have changed somewhere, but this is working fine now. Thanks. But still I am not clear why the same thing did not work from straight query. Is it always we have to do like this for storing string having 4000 and more characters ?

Comment: @K u s H Yes, it's a simple limit of realization.

Answer (score 48):

Try to split the characters into multiple chunks like the query below and try:

```
Insert into table (clob_column) values ( to_clob( 'chunk 1' ) || to_clob( 'chunk 2' ) );
```

It worked for me.

Comment: I confirm, this one worked for me even in simple insert statement to clob column

Comment: this one works, but Is there any disadvantage using to_clob() ?

Answer (score 4):

To solve this issue on my side, I had to use a combo of what was already proposed there

```sql
DECLARE
  chunk1 CLOB; chunk2 CLOB; chunk3 CLOB;
BEGIN
  chunk1 := 'very long literal part 1';
  chunk2 := 'very long literal part 2';
  chunk3 := 'very long literal part 3';

  INSERT INTO table (MY_CLOB)
  SELECT ( chunk1 || chunk2 || chunk3 ) FROM dual;
END;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The split work until 4000 chars depending on the characters that you are inserting. If you are inserting special characters it can fail.
The only secure way is to declare a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Though its a very old question but i think sharing experience still might help others:

Large text can be saved in a single query if we break-down it in chunks of 4000 bytes/characters by concatinating them using '||'

Running following query will tell you:

1. Required Number of chunks containing 4000 bytes
2. Remaining bytes

Since, in given example you are trying to save text contining 15000 bytes (characters), so,

```
select 15000/4000 chunk,mod(15000,4000) remaining_bytes from dual;
```

Result:
[image]

That means, you need to concatenate 3 chunks of 4000 bytes and one chunk of 3000 bytes, so it would be like:

```
INSERT INTO <YOUR_TABLE> 
VALUES (TO_CLOB('<1st_4K_bytes>') || 
        TO_CLOB('<2nd_4K_bytes>') || 
        TO_CLOB('<3rd_4K_bytes>') || 
        TO_CLOB('<last_3K_bytes>)');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. create a function that return a clob

```
create  function  ret_long_chars return clob is
begin

 return to_clob('put here long characters');

end;
```

2. 

```
update table set column = ret_long_chars;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO table(clob_column) SELECT TO_CLOB(q'[chunk1]') || TO_CLOB(q'[chunk2]') ||
            TO_CLOB(q'[chunk3]') || TO_CLOB(q'[chunk4]') FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score -1):

Accepted answer did not work for me in sql developper but combination of this answer and another one did :

```
DECLARE
  str varchar2(32767);
BEGIN
  update table set column = to_clob('Very-very-...-very-very-very-very-very-very long string value');
END;
/
```