# Error : ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to procedure

Tags: oracle

While I call the procedure, it gives me error:

```
ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'UPDATE_LETTER_BODY'
```

Here is my procedure code:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FMIS3.UPDATE_LETTER_BODY IS
    body_text varchar2(32767); 
    condition_id integer;
    begin    
        update FMS_K_OFFICEWISE_LETTER set FKOL_LETTER_BODY=body_text 
        where FKOL_OFFICEWISE_LETTER_ID=condition_id;
    end;
```

Here is how I called it:

```
     CALL UPDATE_LETTER_BODY('test',241);
```

Comment: If seems, for once, to be a fairly self-explanatory error. Your procedure has no parameters...

Comment: Additionally the maximum length of a varchar2 column is 4000, so updating with longer will cause you problems.

Comment: @Ben , Yeah 4000 is the max for CLOB too, but in few blogs, I find declaring as varchar2(32767) which did work but here I could not define the size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out :

```
       CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FMIS3.UPDATE_LETTER_BODY  ( body_text IN FMS_K_OFFICEWISE_LETTER.FKOL_LETTER_BODY%type,condition_id in FMS_K_OFFICEWISE_LETTER.FKOL_OFFICEWISE_LETTER_ID%type)IS
       begin
          update FMS_K_OFFICEWISE_LETTER set FKOL_LETTER_BODY= body_text
          where FKOL_OFFICEWISE_LETTER_ID=condition_id;
       end;
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FMIS3.UPDATE_LETTER_BODY(body_text in varchar2,condition_id in number) IS
begin    
    update FMS_K_OFFICEWISE_LETTER set FKOL_LETTER_BODY=body_text 
    where FKOL_OFFICEWISE_LETTER_ID=condition_id;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FMIS3.UPDATE_LETTER_BODY  ( body_text  IN varchar2,condition_id  in integer ) IS
begin    
    update FMS_K_OFFICEWISE_LETTER set FKOL_LETTER_BODY=body_text 
    where FKOL_OFFICEWISE_LETTER_ID=condition_id;
end;
```

update your proc as above ...

Comment: Thanks but, this solved my syntax problem only, the main problem to set the body_text having more than 4000 chars is not solved. Can't I define size for varchar2 as varchar2(32767) as it gave me error.