# String data to blob column in update query for oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sql-update, blob

I want to execute update query to update blob column. Query is something like this :

```
update table_name set blob_col = 'large text here';
```

But when I execute this, I get error saying :

```
SQL Error: ORA-01704: string literal too long.
```

I saw somewhere when I googled about this to use

```
update table_name set blob_col = utl_raw.cast_to_raw('large text here');
```

But for this also, I'm getting same error `SQL Error: ORA-01704: string literal too long`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error : ORA-01704: string literal too long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945710/error-ora-01704-string-literal-too-long)