# What datatype can I use to store a string of 15000+ characters?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a string of more than 15000 characters.

I'm using long datatype to store the above string, but getting "string literal too long" exception.

Which datatype I should use to store that string in Oracle?

Comment: This seems to be related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945710/error-ora-01704-string-literal-too-long

Comment: You should be using a CLOB rather than `long` - [as the documentation says](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-F6309DF8-162F-48A4-9454-FEE59EC6644F). But you will have the same issue trying to assign a value to it. You need to build it up in chunks; but where is the value actually coming from? if it's in a file there are other things you can do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error : ORA-01704: string literal too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945710/error-ora-01704-string-literal-too-long)

Answer (score 4):

That would be a `CLOB`.

Furthermore, quoting what Alex Poole said in his comment:

> But you will have the same issue trying to assign a value to it. You need to build it up in chunks

Comment: Right; thank you. I quoted your comment, @Alex, if that's all right with you.