# Could not insert a base64 string in a clob data type column

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-insert, clob

I am trying to insert a base64 string in photo column whose data type is clob but i am getting error

```
INSERT INTO myTable
(PHOTO)
VALUES
('data:image/jpeg;base64,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' );
```

**I am getting error**

```
Error at Command Line:9 Column:2
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01704: string literal too long
01704. 00000 -  "string literal too long"
*Cause:    The string literal is longer than 4000 characters.
*Action:   Use a string literal of at most 4000 characters.
           Longer values may only be entered using bind variables.
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13947041/5841306) answer your question ..?

Comment: I couldn't do that manually according to that post, I have to use insert statement to set that string value.

Comment: Just use bind variables (set data type to clob)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution could be to split the string in chunks by return carriage, then you insert and replace the return carriage by a null string. In this case, I use PLSQL

**Keep in mind that I use for my example a very long string but different to yours**

```
declare
vstr clob := q'[ 9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAAEAYABgAAD//gAcQ3JlYXRlZCBieSBBY2N1U29mdCBDb3JwLgD/wAALCAFIASABAREA/9
EA8ODg8eFhcSGSQfJSUjHyIiJyw4MCcqNSoiIjFCMTU6PD8/PyYvRUpEPUk4Pj88AQsLCw8NDx0QEB08KCIoKDw8PDw8PDw8PDw8PDw8PDw8PDw8PDw8PDw
8PDw8PDw8PDw8PDw8PDw8PDw8PDw8PDz/xAAfAAABBQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAQIDBAUGBwgJCgv/xAC1EAACAQMDAgQDBQUEBAnEUMoGRoQgjQrHBFVLR8CQzY
nKCCQoWFxgZGiUmJygpKjQ1Njc4OTpDREVGR0hJSlNUVVZXWFlaY2RlZmdoaWpzdHV2d3h5eoOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPE
xcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4eLj5OXm5+jp6vHy8/T19vf4+fr/2gAIAQEAAD8A9f3GjcaNxp+40bjTNxo3GjcaNxo3GjcaNxo34+bd8tYup+KdN092ill/eD+7XLy+
P7vzmK2iLErfxf3aoS+O9Znf/R2ggU/39tV/+Ez15nPlXy/L979wv/xNP/4TTWdi/wCm/Nzuby12/wDoNC+N9Y2bmu/l42t5a/N/47U8XjzUFkj3MjL/ABK0f/o
NdBYeO4J0XzbSbp8zr92ui0/VrPU0WSyuElWru40bjRuNG40bjRuP96jcaNxo3GjcaNxo3GjcaNxpaKKKKKKKKKjrF1rxLZ6V+7X97Ox27a8+1rxHealN/rfKXP8
AD92sFZol8xdzs2QzN/tU/wAyJoF3M7SsPlX/AIFUUWyRPM3Iu0fd/vf7tMaTy03LviikytEWz5V83duO35/4f9qrFxJBHujtV/cZH3qiikH+sbfuXFWopolg2/3
j92rEUlxbPDNb3bxcbVZJK6jSPGdxHfeXqD+fHj5tkfzLXdWV7b6hB51pKkq1PRRRRRRRRRRUlFFFFFFR1JUdL935q4LxJ4o+12wt9M+6zDMu/qvzVxF7JEs7bfmb
/a/3fvVn/wCv/cL8vO2pWWBU/dK6tzu/2qN3mI25vKVR8u+olZFRdvysx+8lWPtp/wBXKLtWT7q/SolkK7V3fLxT/L/cNI2/+7UsUjqiq2/9592rCtFJuVmdZcjaz
fwrWvp+p3Gmz7omeKXcPM/uyf3VrvdE8S2uoOsEv7q62jcv8Lf7tb9FFFFFFFFFFSUUUUUUUVU1C9i0+1a5uG+Va8+1fxHe6hdSQLL9liY7Ydv8XzfxVyK3B89o/w
DWqo2rVWVXb5fnXaad9mC/7TMN3+sq3FaD5Y9yMzEbd3tUvkjfJ5rbVV/++aZEoX+FGlb/AL5qwsKN8sSov8O5v73+zUTQj+7uZcsy/wB2q7WSNuVmdt33V/z6VLF
p1qybfN+Zf71NW0uo9vlLuVT/AAUyW2uF+ZvlVhu2p/dqurbXk3Rbtw+Zf7tWFmMjt5qp/u/3f92rtrdpO6/fWVcsrf3sV6j4c1WPUtKj3S/viiiiiivOPFXiU3ry
WNun7iNzub/aDVyKwz7/ALS33lHy09bYQJ8q7pfu7qd5J+VWb5VO2iKEr5ke7czYVlq3FaGT94v98fKu2pVsC3nMv8OdypH5jbv+BUW9lunVYt7Ny1OaPz0j+ZGib
5vmqKW08z5v7v8AD/eWoPsm3bt+8xO5alVSqfLs3fdpzM/95Pm+Vv7rUL+8RfNXv96pV0uK5fy9qRNIP4Kzb3QpbaBm/iX5dtVZVl2Rxy7938K/3sLT7W9uLGeGa3
Z1lZD5bf3l/u17NpWqWuq2QmtZUb+Fl/utV2ipKjqSiiiiiiiiiiiuS8Z6w9sn2S1lRWZD5leeLsZ2Zl3bj/H95qtxQ/eVfur/AA+Z607btSP5vWrUUKM6r91W/vf
w4q6tgF+X73Pzf7tOWEb9zfMv3fkjqx9ki2fLsZv/AEJf7tC2z/L5WxWb5V2U+W0ikf5d8S8r8/tWe1ptdtuzbn738NRS2x+98nyndu+lVZVEjtt+VuFX+7TW2L5a
/dZh/wB9VPbr/Cvy7sNWrbx+ZP8AMvy/3v71X4owyKu1FX+HbWbqGhRTwSbm3M2WVv7tctqFpPpU6wSqjfxf7taPh3U/7Bvlu1R2ik/dyL/d/wBqXFYNtZfu0+iii
iiiiiiiiiisbX9Yi0iwaR0dpW+Vdqfxba81v5Jr2aa5uvmZlO3/wCyoslSSCPa23cPu/8AxNXVj8jd833f4X/vf+hUzy9sG3+Jsbv71a9lCd6tuRl+9V2K0/h+f5s
fL9KtrabtrN91TUq2QXcy/dpjWQX5l3/L/DTZbRP9v/4qq/k/d+VGb73zfdqrdWRj+6qfvP8Ax2qUto/3rj+L+L/ZqvLbjft3bmx91v8Aeqxawv8A3flb5v8AZrXi
hC/kVq7FH8m3bT/L+7t96x9dsEntWVlf5gN2z7y1wiw/ZN1s3nK33v8AWfK3+7XoXgjVvPjbTZW3Sx5Zf9pd3+1XX1JRRRRRRRRRRRTGYKm5v4a8p1XVHvr6aRmfy
mwu3+78tRW//H15m7azfLt8z/x7dV1cNOu5kaKPHzU6WN1+ZfmibLfNVu1tw21fK+Zfl3f5atq3j+dd3zNV+KMLVhVH/AqGX+Kjb/sU1o6pNGW/9lpjY+7t28/LVe
WFF3bV2q3zNsqrdWwk+VWf/Z3VLFD8m1d67fu1dVdr/dqVc/Lu+7UqrRKoZNv/AAKuQ8Sw26uskqp+7Ibd9P4aybK7Omz293aq+5fu/wC0v3tteq6Zexalp0N7b/6
uRat0Uzn7tPoooooooorE8UXpsrGMJs3SPt+avN7eNNiqquyx/eq/EtvOjMsW3ah+VPvVoRR/8tFVF8wDc1Hlo26SX7uP++c1q28JZ9vyVfij/f1dVQv+63y0/aF+
Wjb97dRTGXd96q8sZ+8tQS/cZf4Wqo2fl3fdX+Gqsrf89f8AdqWJtyKu35l/hq15h+9/dqZW/wC+qnX760+sDXVtWRo71fl4Zm/u1zF1bvB5KxM7Rbx8391q6vwRq
O77RpbfL5Z8yP8A2lLNurs6KKKKKKKKKKK4Xxxfv9qjgi/5Zj/nnvrFW3Ek/wA2zylG75P/AEKrdrDEqTKtx+9U/NVrbuRlVd237tS26hU3NvbgblStKL7+32q2rf
8AfNWlp+6mbv4d1H+9RUTNtrPlY7/4P9qoGbzP+A/w1Du+833v4mVv/ZqFkDbWVv8AvmSnqx+78nzfKtWFYfwt/vfhVpW+RW3f7VWN3yK1ZuqwxTo0cvy7vl3J96u
GurK6juo2ibzYl+b/AHqk0KY2muWflO67ZYY2/wB12+61ev0UUUUUUUUUUn8debaqxk1W6+0b18vDN/y0X/gNRKySJ5211nxt+b+HNW1Uttbd8y/Lu/vVaVT91m3c
7V/2asRKNn3dqsd1WrdQ1XVx8tWFWn7qKZ8tNb5d27/xyq8sg3t9KryqF/h+XNReWFfd/F/eqvLGP9Z/dG1aY0Y2Nub0Xa0dHyL8q/KuD96pYmRX/L/dq8rf984qV
WPy/WqWoKG+X+78y/7VchqFt9h2yS/Nu+XbVNv+Prdt3Nn73+1/DXq+jy+do1lJu3M0C7m/4DV6iiiiiiiiiivLtVUtrNw23zYFH3fM+apbVg26NV2xMny7q0FysC
q0vm/3qn/56ff6/N96nxfNu+buKtLJEu7c23adtaETBvmWrC7P71H8FM3UNiq8v8P1pqx7vmb5v9qiVf3FV2Us/wAuxf4qZz/rG2VX8v5Pl+VaNp/u/wD2VG3bt2/N
/DVhcr9771WN33WouMNB935WrmNSjeefyfKfytn3qyNQhMHy7UVWA/4DXpPhr/kV9O/64J/6DWrRRRRRRRRRRXleuyD/AISSZVV24Dba0rWPy0aBW+7/ANNPSrqru
3fxbvlpssxV9rNt3f8AoIqlLdlX/dN97+Ks+KSVfmi+VVTazN/eoutdvINrfw//AGNVV8Sz71bd82f++q1YvFAnRVlbb0q+uvjz2XzUaJgGjatj+0YPlX/lq38NMl
YNt+b/AHqliuEX/a21FLcIv8W5m/75WqTX8Uf8W5v9iqsutRLPt/ib/wBBFZTeI5W2tbq/T5pW/drtpi+IyqR+bEiq2dzf3afF4hf/AFflbVzt3J/DXRaVdpqFpuX
Z8p+bbV/y/vbf96pdu5NrVi3unFdrLK+3H3v4q5HUFSO6aTd+9w/3v4a9L8L/APIr6Z827/Ro/wD0Gtiiiiio6kooqOpK8z8QKV8STeU21tgb/V/wmteK2ECL/E3O
6m/x/wB1ePl8uql0wbcu75cn/vqiK0lV13RbmjFF7o6X277Uzr/Ev7ysHUNCuo9rbnlb+7/drK+xBfvL+9prRmP5m+ZWPyr9aYtwY9rN8u01r6bqJg27pX6fdSteW
9Mk6/faL+JfMX5atLdvAny/NuG7/erK1DWn2SKrIqyYX/arn5dUl3/K371SfvVU852nVvnZf9r+KpVuJZNu1nVlH3k/i/2aFZ/ljVflYVYt7K6bduXa38TNJ93NbO
jyXFtuZm+Xhd1dppVwbm1XzW+b/wBCrQ2n9Kz9VXcm7a/y/N/wGuE1CRG1VvK/hA/4FXqujwrbaNZQr91Yl/8AQatVJRRUdFSUUVHUled+LY0tvEjSM26JoA23/a3
PW02fIVv7w/nVS4Xy4G/Gqqwz71a4/wB75K19Pt0XbtX/AGWb+9Wh9mH8XzVXuIR/3zWBqUMTJt/iXLM396ubntINjMvk/MfveZ96suW3K7tzJ8orS0+0Rn+XY3P/A
D0+7XR2+j+YnzLuVsfNVXUtNlg3fNu3A/8AAcVympKV2/3ud1ZiqW27V3Vdt4Xk+X+LP3a6nT/Dm7a3lJ838X92tiLR4o9y7f8Avv71Ma3Lbdv3l/vfxUyXTn/eMsr
t5n8NWNNmMG2Nl/df3v8AgP8AFXSKwbdVXUFLWjbWTcoNeeLCY9djgiZGZZ49u/8AibdXrsWVSPd97A3VNRRUdFFSUUUVHzv3buw+WuE+ItvJvt7iKLdkeXu/77ral
X5FZfdaz5f7vz1B5yfvGXe3O356cuu2un/eb5VxWbe/ECCB/wB1buy/9dKy7rxjrU9o1yunPFBz+98tttZv/CTXU7tHuRmb7u+mLqkrf63Yq/d+atO1ZLncsS/LgfN9
K09PthY3yrKz7cHbXbrIip8uysXUr1N+35Onzbq4zxBsaeRol+9n5qyrWyeR1X+981dNprWdim6XZ/47tWrcviqzj+6rsqmoW8XJPtVVRvMJXb5lQf8ACQj7V5jWj
r/7KtXLXxHayTqzfKuP++q29qMkbKvy4+WtKykH3fenXHzQSfQtXnmnsk+s2jbtzfaY9qt/vV63/dpKkooqOipKKKKZLII4Gkb+GuK8YXjXelCOe32rncrf3flrQb/j0
Vv++qoXC/uJJG+7j5q5jWr+Vd0duu5mJ2t8u3isOK0uJ763jume387/AJay/wANdXqXhm30PTY73T1e4njlDM38TLWTdeLtRuYPI+0J5Ej/ADK0f3lP8NT6PDb65dTS
agqRWtpEFj2fw1Qi0fU13TWkT3Vqp+Vk+8qiur8P6LbyWMNzu/2tqVNqGyC6h2/981at5H2LIy/M3ystVdQUtO38K4Py/wDAf7tcndWxg1KH/nllFrUaweRNsX3sBlX+6
v8AeasHUm3XX2TTLd7j7OP3jJH97Fa17o+neHPsdzqyPq7SIfl/5ZRt/D8tU9X1HRNQmWODRobWCM+ZuSP5m/2flqK30eLUEvZtP3r5ZHlr/rFrIlWe2nkjuN8Usfy7q2
tH1+W2RYLj5ov9v7tdxpVx58CyL8v8LVtXWPsszf7BrkvA+l/ab5r2VXaOM7l3f3tz16LRRRRUdSUUVHRVXVbQ3umzWyvskYfK30rgbK/fVdKa21NfKvIR8y/+zV1NxlU
X+Km+SGgamW9lFG7Sbfvf99VE1lBPO32iJKlt9lsiqv8Aql+X5v4a5u90vw557N5TrPnc0UO7/wBBpixwKm1Ynt4FPy7v4f8AgP3q0NNsop0aOJX8pgN2yT5WxWldSQaf
a+XEzxKo2r/s1kL5tzfeZu+6AtaW7/a/3lqrLIjP/s1U1KyE6bvk/vKz1Qiu92mtHu+bn/pmq4q/pVlFaWknlS3X77G5V/hzRqH2Wex+yXrO391m+9trnP7Hi8+Pyr5GX
IVtn3q6ayU2yfZNPbyosDczbada6BYtdST3W+WVhuZm/vVQl8MwRvuiX733a2vD9l9hTy2/3a3L1Q2m3St93yn+/wD7tcjpsN15FutvdzW65HmRJ/kV3OlSFrXbu3eXhd
zVcooqSio6kooopjf6tq8i0Rri+1Wa52v8qeXuau9ul3fxURN8m3+H7tWG+Z6b5Yk+981V2tH/ANiopbK4+XayK33fkquuko0/mXDPLtx977taDSD/AFcS/drHuI3V22/N
0+5UUsiWm1m+Xj/vqoluH3x7vm3H+L+9/wABqWLP2pfv/MQu2rTKNkfy/MoNZrWnlz7l+aJgd391atWv+jOu7/VMv3mq3cWUVzt/2sfd/irFl0I/dZUbj73+rpy2Ev7vcz
7Vy1atlD5D/K33vvVd2/PuqaJf4ttXJV3QSL/eQ1wOsasbSxVl/wBb92NX/vD+79K7nwor/wDCKadJL/rZoEkb/eK1r0VJUdFFSUUVHUlcbqFolokltaLt8xw0n+1V/UPu
L/FUUTfd/h3VdX/ZWpfvf+zUcLTWY/wrTGjMn+9Q0aRwNWLL825dyLtNZVwvmT7mb+DbWha2EvkR+U3zY+9/s1L9k2v/AB9lq3FGdi7vvLn5qY0e5KZ5Y2bafbs6/K33f7
1DTCTarLtp/wB7cy7PmH3ql2/d/wC+W2U7+NfpVhYwyfd+WpZV/cN9DXA+K1tb7wvYalpku5bSfa2z/bb5v/Hq9D0SMweH9Phb70dtGrf981doooooooooqSsfUI0kn3bf
mWq90paBfuVFF99v4f8Aeq1Fj/vqrG4U371G2nUyVd33vu1z2qyBXaNd+5jTLWEtdbt3y4Hzf3q6qKMRp81V72Pcny1EuF+WqVxmP7q+u2ofODbtrIy5+b+9U3Dbf4uR96
jy0Xd8vysPmpnH/Ac/NT1b+L/PNSq27+H/AIFVqL/ZqVvuVxem2D/8THSJf9V9ph+VfeXdXo6rt2r/AHRtpKKKKKKKKKkorldakMGpRyeb97C7f71WLpf3C7l+ZTVeJhvX
cydfvVaWQ/wruqVW/wDHv4asf+PU2pfvVDL9xv4VrAW0SeeSa6+b5yyq392ori4ia6WCJvmx95albWJY9u75V4Zt1RXHiHcnyrt/2qzZdWlg3XP2jdE33tn/ALL/APrq1o
+vxXKeXcfe/hq7dLFBdrIv3ZB/BViJgz/K27n/AL5qX+P/AMeprNu/3V/vVCyhvut81Kuf4vm/9Bq+rfw7v++qsfwfN92s/RY/P1W4mb2b/wCJrpKKKKKKKKKKKkrl9dkE
bs0sW5VG5afFMJ9Njb+Fk3VVaQK/zN8v8NSrIP4tm2rUTfJ/Buare77tJu3VN/BVe4+WBv8AarzvWtfntkkgXerKfu/8CrlLVdYadZoldv4Wrf1LUfM/d+b82R/y0+7VLz
i0Ei/61cH722qusXFxcpDbRf6qP+FP71Urf7RBu+ba33VruNEke5tVWVvlX5V3f7v8NdFFJudfmRf71S/eT7v3v+mdN3De21aYzHf91P8AaoaQsm1v+BbqsRNt/wBnrV24
U/YZlX73lPUXheMrBuZXVsbWVq3qKKKKKKKKKKKyNd06a78uS1+8pG5arrGV01VaLyto+7/drNuPlRt33VO6nxM6/wB/5flq1FIf97+7VtWOz5acrf3WqZpKqXEw2Mq1yu
saAl88kkX7pm+arGj6FBp6N5v+kN/eqXVdF0y7tGjiVIpc/erD/wCEOeNF3Xf/ANlTG0WCT5V/dLwu7/LU218L+XOsksu7aN0f92tq3t9u7b93/wBlq/Ev3f8AllT1+58y
9j8tMb5UVWV23GopW3bV27f9qm+cPP27fXbV+Jt25f4v9qruoSGPTbpvu7Yj81S+H98lq1zLLu8zFa9FFFFFFFFFFFFU9SX7rVzt0o3/ADKnmr93d71VVtu7zdn+0qVPbz
RKi/N977v41dVgr7asbt33aezbv/ZapN/FuqvLMFRvmfav3v8AZqq12nzKrIv+5WfLd+fPHH7j9K0NQu/kVt27cNq1mLcD7d83yt/D/vVpRfM+3du3AbtlWNu3738JqxtP
8LVE2NjKy7eKiuGG9tu/dVRvln8z5933fm/hobLT/LvrTt4yvy7e9a8tp9rtJLbdtVhtartrbJaWiwRfdWp6KKKKKKKKKKKKgvYxJatu/h+aubus72Vf/wBqqO4Sfd/h+W
T/AGqIm+78vlKvy7qtxSbf4u1WuV+b+7Q2Nm7+7VK4uBHu+b5s1SWO+1J1+zrtikI+Zv8Avr71adv4cs40b7Qz3DMd1MuNFt96+Uzqqmqv2SBd3ms7f7lQ/ZrVdzRSurNl
dtRbXg+b5FViPmq6sx3qu19q/wANWIm/yn8K07htu3ZUVxhflX5lWqTb2fa3zNT/ACfkXcu5l/76/wD2a0rVdv8AD90Vv2v3N1WqKKKKKKKKKKKKKay7kZW/iFYF1jeyt8
u2sWVjv3L93JZqZ/e+b73973qVfl+VflZjWhuEaL81V5WMny/e2/8ATT1qJlg37r2VGZQFVau2+qIqeWv3vurRcaokHl7m+VjRb3HmJ8retZ9xepHP97/9moLi/DfNtSV
V+bdVdtRGzauyJvvfNJT4r23kSRf9VKtQremPdt9RHt8z/wAeraWT5Ny7P+AUSyBk+9VX+P5vm61at12/wuy1dt127tvv81dBEu1FWnU6iiiiiiiiiiiiisjWFEc6tt+WT+K
sC6X51VpX3ZP3KpNIP+Ar93f7VYXDOq7trN81StcbYGZWSsPUNRECSN/F/EtYen3F/qGpfKryysf+BLmtmXRdWnnZWZFVafceHtWa1X5kl242slZrSarbIrbX+bKtsqgzX0k
7KsU3zU6WHU/3kaq+371V9t8u1WWZeC3/AAKoPtbrOrbvmrX0+/lZ41l/4DXQ2V6disuzvurQlkdvm/hzu+eq+5F3f7X7zdV+3y237nfdsrV0+Pz32/w/eatqinU2nUUUU2n
UUUUUUVBew/abVlX7yg7a5W4Usnzep3NWK0m1Gkbe0uflqxattf5l+Zc/cqu1wdkjRN907m2f+y0+3x58c7fMqkfe963LdbOS6jkVUilX/wAerVt2iZ2VvvVd3RbKqy2lnJt
ZlRWb5aJbSzX5lVNyjbuqv5duu77m3NVZVt5EZV2NuH8Fcxe2GnW19JcqqNP97a33WzWNcYW6jZV9P0q9as/nqsu/5vu/7P8A3zWm0m3zPK2bv4f/AGaofORtv+zlfnrYt22
wfeRdo2/NXSaVCYIGZt7NJ83zVdooop1FFNop1FFFFFFFc9rtuFdmXZtkB/76rk723P8AE23aPm/d0K23b83yyf7tRSt87bvJ/wBmnecnzL97pub+9VeW4eOfzIm+6S3yVq2
uv/J5dx8sq/K1aS67FIn+tRl/2P71PbUbVX3eany4qve6xbqjSLKjfL92sXUNaRtvlN8qg/8AAqptrTqm2Jnqq128iMzL+9z/ABRr3pm7c+5WTa3y/wC822rEUw37tqNwf+A
rWjul2NtbauP4PZqfar+//veZ/DXSaZbG5nXd8sSj95/tZrp6KKKdTadRTaKdRRRRRRRWRrDDz41/hYHdXO3UJ+b+Ld8tZcreRubdtVqpSsVdlbf+7xuX+7UUskreY3mv82N
27/dqBpD9kZd3+9/s1ntlf4vlb7y1XaSdvl3O3Sq/nXH8XzLTfMlbb/tf+O05Wf8Aiqa33yf391Wlbb/u/wAWyrG4qjR7vu/+hVYiY/eXftX7v7v7tair/seirV+yj+8qrtl
U/NXX6PNZ/ZPskEu6SH5ZF/i3VpUUUUUU6iim8b6dRRRRRTZWdYGaJd0ir8q/3qfu/vVi6lMk7rt+ZVytZVxlk3L/AOOVi3sZX5WVGXBb5v4apSxlt0krPu5/76qJowv+1z9
2m/Zvkbd8v8Kt/dqe30sM/wA33V+6396r66BFsXd97FNl0Wwjg2yy7WX5v+BVl3Gl2/zfvU+X71Z8ulovmKsvp8v+1UH2KWP+58oNSrD5abvN71KqhkXb/Fhtr1dt8K/737v
G6rkUjyPt+Tdzt31sabbiN1bbuZvvfhWPp+o7fE96u75vtMjLXo1vMJ03LViiiiinUU2jmnVJUdFFFFZ2q3G2Bo1bbwd1YUU32m0Vl+bcTT2/h/h/9mrK1BfkX+Ff/QazZcK
nmfIvNMZv4f733f8AeqVWiWCSRW3Lk7qFuNsG7+JfmWntrX93Z027apS6oW+bzUlVht3eXUX20/6tvl/2qbcTBtu3YrZP93/x2hpom27tm5fvK9ObG/5f4fu/7K1E0m1927bu/ib7
rLT4syT7vuxKu3/ZrRt4/nVfvLkN/wACFdFZZX5mb/gVedWUm26urld+5p5P/Qq9P0e7LIvzfdB+9XQK25Plp1FFFOooptOoooooqCeby9y/xVyviK42wSMzdizVQ8LzfadChkb7r
E7q1dvyLuqGWMbNrL+6b71ZF7bOqSNEz9D8v8Lf7NYzSOz7l+9nayt95flqJrgKkm35lyN341D9rdn+8i8/89Kq3E3yfx9d3zVV85/4v/2qcsm12ZlRv+2lS/aCr7lbt/wJqeszq7
bl+bFS/az8rbvmzu2/NQuJ925vK4/76rVijKoqyruZfm/2av2X7tI9yurN96tfd5drcTNv/dxFq860pvnX+LcT+tdxa3Zg2szeq119lcBtv92tKiijdRRTqKKKKKKVm2/NWPcSf+P
V554wvS07W25/mzWr4MXb4Xt/4V+9W5xsVW/76oZfn+7tqrKoZGVt6q39azbrTomfav8AED830rAvbDyLVmVty53SbPvVis38Lb9tV2kPy7f4qbuP3fpRu2v81CybvmX/AIDTl376
t2tuWf5vl/u1tWtsWRv++mb+61XIlOxlX/VN95f7tWrdir/7K7FX/Z/3qsarMbbw/ezL/ChVfxridKjOxd2zbjbXSLM6zq3yKuP4K6nSpB+72/LuG7bXRW8nybasUUUUUUU6iim0M
wVNzVSaYyJu/hrNvZDHAzf3R81eW+KLjddLJ/FJnc1dX4Pwvhu1/usm75/et9f4dzVL9522rUDRld21vlX/AL6qo38S7UqLy9yL8yMv8X7v71Zsthbz/NL/AKpSY6oar4egW0W
S0/dN/wAtF/2a5PyS3+7QsO7b9yr8VkGRvl3LmtCKML/f6DctaMUab1ba+7nctNlZNkcm7dztp0XzOqr8rKNrN/D96tJVCv8ANs3MPvJt+asnxRMW0q4VtjMuF/8AHqyNHXd5e7f8
2d3/AHzW35Zk/ef8BrotNkKuq/xN/DXS27fJuq6rbkp1FFFFFOoptG4VSuJCz/LUUrBYFXbWbesPIb/a+WvKvFC7b5dvzfOW/wDQK7PwopXQrVW+9sFb8SlU3fxVL/Gu1vlqKVUZP
mZF5G3/AGqpXUb71/h/2v71N3Dfu83cymqksg2bvkbn7yf5/rUXmPGiq2+WJvvVzMqhn3bfu/3v8/eqpuG9V/iqwuG3NKz/AO6n8XzVdiY/6z7u3+L+LmrDMV+6vzKDtpyxld3zbV
X+593/AGqsbh8sar6/cpzKVeRf7pG7/arG8RMWsfLbf8x+Xd7VFpUYby9yo3+9/u10LL8jbvm3At/vfw1d0dRv/g3fd3eZ96unt/lTbV9amVhRQtO3UUUUU1pBH96qTXG77q0RSbv
mqGXDf7q1QuvvzfiteZeM/wB3rK/N8uP4P71dN4U/5BVuv3fkT/0Guki+58v/AHzT2UfLTN3ybv7tV5W+fbt+Vhu3VSlhdfm/5ZL/ABJ/DVVmK7f4uPvVm3Vx5fzfw4+9WHLcS+ez
Kvzcf+g1X8w71+b5m/vVKqiN9v3f9qrcTBd21f3v8X+7WguF+98zZ+7/AHc07du3fK+1fvfvP/Qanix8qxe3/Af7tMlZF3eb/wB8/wAW6ue8QSfdWtjSrYRwLIu/purW2jZGzfMv9
2tXTF2ou1vu/wAL1r2rH7vz/wDAqu8/xU9vmTdQsn+1T/MK/wC7UqyBqfuoqi1+W+WKL/gVRJe3Uj/vVRV4+7Rz96m7f71OX5d31pvLfw/NVK6zsZtvzV5544hl8+OZl+Zidrf98V
r+GpP9Ejj+f5QGrp1y3ysv/fVS7v8AKVFuPy/+yUyX5v7/AFNV5VMaK21Opqq0Y3tJt8rd/D/erKvYfL+791vlrGuLcN96Ldx8uz+9VdYSu3+FmP8A3zT1j/1a/e2n/gNTqo/2F4q
3/tNv3fwr/e/z9al5+6u/p/49QzBtvyv8ufmXdTJW8vczK67T97/7GuevW8+eH5flz/F/vV12nqFgjXdu/wByr6w7kZm/dLj5q0rWE7G2qityyq1Ytv4ss2uljaXyufmby/lrrLXU
Uk8tW/5afdZPu1prUTLt+VvutRzSKu77rbamViv+7Uu6sdV+fctPaR2/9mWhZN3+zUvHyt/EtP3f7VV2bdu+b5ar3CjY23/vlv4q57xRYG50aRfK+Zgdq/3WFYHhe4KvtZU/3mrto
vm+7T9259rb9tM8wsis38Xy/wC781MlUf3fvZ3VFt3O38Srn/8Aaqvu3Jtb+HNUrqP5F+X7pH3P4qybiP5I/wB6m1vu/wC1UUtuI/l+7u+7UPG9t3qG3VYiVNitF6/L/wAs6N3yM3y
My/w1YZdvy/3vvf7NRKw37V3r5f3m/i21Xupvk/urztrN02PzNZj3K+2P5mrvbW2Pyr/CuP8AgVXfLLPt/wCBbf8AaqLWr0aZoV1N/EqFY/8AaYr8teZW8PmPtX7zEfN/eru/C8yLYrb
XC/Z7pvmjZvuy4rXstR23zWzK9u3/ACz3/dl/3a34pBco395fvU2KT5Pm+9ipd3+1QrU/dWb5h2baZu+T5vajzP7vytirC42bfuqtG4/wtUX/AAF6Yy/P81Yuu4Xy1+euUlj/ALP1VWV
f3FwSy7P4a6vT5tyK25KsNIPmaL0H60MwVP8AW/8AAU/ipjSBflVvm5+X+7TFYq7bm3Lk/wDAaguF8v5t
33j97zPL25qlcNudW2urfxf7NUJZPuwrvZs7m/z/APXqk0gj3fLt3H5v9qomkO/d97cRUtv+8fayuu771WGYqkfzbdv9aiZSqbV/iP3Wpm4xorfOu0bvyqrdNu2rt27f+mn3q1PC9
gfmudv+sPy7vau2t/ufd+XG1f8Ad/2asSsF+98u37tch44m8z/iXr/y7kMzf3mK1zNlaFv3n/Aq6u1jLWLWjLubAZVb+9VJoZ5EaO4a62qdu3zPu11llduqM3zyyrlm/wBpa0L2Sa
Pbc2ipL/z03SUz7W6p+9t32/7FTW9wkjsqt82Pu/xVaXOz5q//2Q== ]';
begin
insert into t ( c1 ) values ( replace( vstr , chr(13) , '' )  ) ;
commit;
end;
/
```

Then you run the script

```
SQL> desc t
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 C1                                                 CLOB

SQL> host cat insert.sql
declare
vstr clob := q'[9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAAEAYABgAAD//gAcQ3JlYXRlZCBieSBBY2N1U29mdCBDb3JwLgD/wAALCAFIASABAREA/9
EA8ODg8eFhcSGSQfJSUjHyIiJyw4MCcqNSoiIjFCMTU6PD8/PyYvRUpEPUk4Pj88AQsLCw8NDx0QEB08KCIoKDw8PDw8PDw8PDw8PDw8PDw8PDw8PDw8PDw
8PDw8PDw8PDw8PDw8PDw8PDw8PDw8PDz/xAAfAAABBQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAQIDBAUGBwgJCgv/xAC1EAACAQMDAgQDBQUEBAnEUMoGRoQgjQrHBFVLR8CQzY
nKCCQoWFxgZGiUmJygpKjQ1Njc4OTpDREVGR0hJSlNUVVZXWFlaY2RlZmdoaWpzdHV2d3h5eoOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPE
xcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4eLj5OXm5+jp6vHy8/T19vf4+fr/2gAIAQEAAD8A9f3GjcaNxp+40bjTNxo3GjcaNxo3GjcaNxo34+bd8tYup+KdN092ill/eD+7XLy+
P7vzmK2iLErfxf3aoS+O9Znf/R2ggU/39tV/+Ez15nPlXy/L979wv/xNP/4TTWdi/wCm/Nzuby12/wDoNC+N9Y2bmu/l42t5a/N/47U8XjzUFkj3MjL/ABK0f/o
NdBYeO4J0XzbSbp8zr92ui0/VrPU0WSyuElWru40bjRuNG40bjRuP96jcaNxo3GjcaNxo3GjcaNxpaKKKKKKKKKjrF1rxLZ6V+7X97Ox27a8+1rxHealN/rfKXP8
AD92sFZol8xdzs2QzN/tU/wAyJoF3M7SsPlX/AIFUUWyRPM3Iu0fd/vf7tMaTy03LviikytEWz5V83duO35/4f9qrFxJBHujtV/cZH3qiikH+sbfuXFWopolg2/3
j92rEUlxbPDNb3bxcbVZJK6jSPGdxHfeXqD+fHj5tkfzLXdWV7b6hB51pKkq1PRRRRRRRRRRUlFFFFFFR1JUdL935q4LxJ4o+12wt9M+6zDMu/qvzVxF7JEs7bfmb
/a/3fvVn/wCv/cL8vO2pWWBU/dK6tzu/2qN3mI25vKVR8u+olZFRdvysx+8lWPtp/wBXKLtWT7q/SolkK7V3fLxT/L/cNI2/+7UsUjqiq2/9592rCtFJuVmdZcjaz
fwrWvp+p3Gmz7omeKXcPM/uyf3VrvdE8S2uoOsEv7q62jcv8Lf7tb9FFFFFFFFFFSUUUUUUUVU1C9i0+1a5uG+Va8+1fxHe6hdSQLL9liY7Ydv8XzfxVyK3B89o/w
DWqo2rVWVXb5fnXaad9mC/7TMN3+sq3FaD5Y9yMzEbd3tUvkjfJ5rbVV/++aZEoX+FGlb/AL5qwsKN8sSov8O5v73+zUTQj+7uZcsy/wB2q7WSNuVmdt33V/z6VLF
p1qybfN+Zf71NW0uo9vlLuVT/AAUyW2uF+ZvlVhu2p/dqurbXk3Rbtw+Zf7tWFmMjt5qp/u/3f92rtrdpO6/fWVcsrf3sV6j4c1WPUtKj3S/viiiiiivOPFXiU3ry
WNun7iNzub/aDVyKwz7/ALS33lHy09bYQJ8q7pfu7qd5J+VWb5VO2iKEr5ke7czYVlq3FaGT94v98fKu2pVsC3nMv8OdypH5jbv+BUW9lunVYt7Ny1OaPz0j+ZGib
5vmqKW08z5v7v8AD/eWoPsm3bt+8xO5alVSqfLs3fdpzM/95Pm+Vv7rUL+8RfNXv96pV0uK5fy9qRNIP4Kzb3QpbaBm/iX5dtVZVl2Rxy7938K/3sLT7W9uLGeGa3
Z1lZD5bf3l/u17NpWqWuq2QmtZUb+Fl/utV2ipKjqSiiiiiiiiiiiuS8Z6w9sn2S1lRWZD5leeLsZ2Zl3bj/H95qtxQ/eVfur/AA+Z607btSP5vWrUUKM6r91W/vf
w4q6tgF+X73Pzf7tOWEb9zfMv3fkjqx9ki2fLsZv/AEJf7tC2z/L5WxWb5V2U+W0ikf5d8S8r8/tWe1ptdtuzbn738NRS2x+98nyndu+lVZVEjtt+VuFX+7TW2L5a
/dZh/wB9VPbr/Cvy7sNWrbx+ZP8AMvy/3v71X4owyKu1FX+HbWbqGhRTwSbm3M2WVv7tctqFpPpU6wSqjfxf7taPh3U/7Bvlu1R2ik/dyL/d/wBqXFYNtZfu0+iii
iiiiiiiiiisbX9Yi0iwaR0dpW+Vdqfxba81v5Jr2aa5uvmZlO3/wCyoslSSCPa23cPu/8AxNXVj8jd833f4X/vf+hUzy9sG3+Jsbv71a9lCd6tuRl+9V2K0/h+f5s
fL9KtrabtrN91TUq2QXcy/dpjWQX5l3/L/DTZbRP9v/4qq/k/d+VGb73zfdqrdWRj+6qfvP8Ax2qUto/3rj+L+L/ZqvLbjft3bmx91v8Aeqxawv8A3flb5v8AZrXi
hC/kVq7FH8m3bT/L+7t96x9dsEntWVlf5gN2z7y1wiw/ZN1s3nK33v8AWfK3+7XoXgjVvPjbTZW3Sx5Zf9pd3+1XX1JRRRRRRRRRRRTGYKm5v4a8p1XVHvr6aRmfy
mwu3+78tRW//H15m7azfLt8z/x7dV1cNOu5kaKPHzU6WN1+ZfmibLfNVu1tw21fK+Zfl3f5atq3j+dd3zNV+KMLVhVH/AqGX+Kjb/sU1o6pNGW/9lpjY+7t28/LVe
WFF3bV2q3zNsqrdWwk+VWf/Z3VLFD8m1d67fu1dVdr/dqVc/Lu+7UqrRKoZNv/AAKuQ8Sw26uskqp+7Ibd9P4aybK7Omz293aq+5fu/wC0v3tteq6Zexalp0N7b/6
uRat0Uzn7tPoooooooorE8UXpsrGMJs3SPt+avN7eNNiqquyx/eq/EtvOjMsW3ah+VPvVoRR/8tFVF8wDc1Hlo26SX7uP++c1q28JZ9vyVfij/f1dVQv+63y0/aF+
Wjb97dRTGXd96q8sZ+8tQS/cZf4Wqo2fl3fdX+Gqsrf89f8AdqWJtyKu35l/hq15h+9/dqZW/wC+qnX760+sDXVtWRo71fl4Zm/u1zF1bvB5KxM7Rbx8391q6vwRq
O77RpbfL5Z8yP8A2lLNurs6KKKKKKKKKKK4Xxxfv9qjgi/5Zj/nnvrFW3Ek/wA2zylG75P/AEKrdrDEqTKtx+9U/NVrbuRlVd237tS26hU3NvbgblStKL7+32q2rf
8AfNWlp+6mbv4d1H+9RUTNtrPlY7/4P9qoGbzP+A/w1Du+833v4mVv/ZqFkDbWVv8AvmSnqx+78nzfKtWFYfwt/vfhVpW+RW3f7VWN3yK1ZuqwxTo0cvy7vl3J96u
GurK6juo2ibzYl+b/AHqk0KY2muWflO67ZYY2/wB12+61ev0UUUUUUUUUUn8debaqxk1W6+0b18vDN/y0X/gNRKySJ5211nxt+b+HNW1Uttbd8y/Lu/vVaVT91m3c
7V/2asRKNn3dqsd1WrdQ1XVx8tWFWn7qKZ8tNb5d27/xyq8sg3t9KryqF/h+XNReWFfd/F/eqvLGP9Z/dG1aY0Y2Nub0Xa0dHyL8q/KuD96pYmRX/L/dq8rf984qV
WPy/WqWoKG+X+78y/7VchqFt9h2yS/Nu+XbVNv+Prdt3Nn73+1/DXq+jy+do1lJu3M0C7m/4DV6iiiiiiiiiivLtVUtrNw23zYFH3fM+apbVg26NV2xMny7q0FysC
q0vm/3qn/56ff6/N96nxfNu+buKtLJEu7c23adtaETBvmWrC7P71H8FM3UNiq8v8P1pqx7vmb5v9qiVf3FV2Us/wAuxf4qZz/rG2VX8v5Pl+VaNp/u/wD2VG3bt2/N
/DVhcr9771WN33WouMNB935WrmNSjeefyfKfytn3qyNQhMHy7UVWA/4DXpPhr/kV9O/64J/6DWrRRRRRRRRRRXleuyD/AISSZVV24Dba0rWPy0aBW+7/ANNPSrqru
3fxbvlpssxV9rNt3f8AoIqlLdlX/dN97+Ks+KSVfmi+VVTazN/eoutdvINrfw//AGNVV8Sz71bd82f++q1YvFAnRVlbb0q+uvjz2XzUaJgGjatj+0YPlX/lq38NMl
YNt+b/AHqliuEX/a21FLcIv8W5m/75WqTX8Uf8W5v9iqsutRLPt/ib/wBBFZTeI5W2tbq/T5pW/drtpi+IyqR+bEiq2dzf3afF4hf/AFflbVzt3J/DXRaVdpqFpuX
Z8p+bbV/y/vbf96pdu5NrVi3unFdrLK+3H3v4q5HUFSO6aTd+9w/3v4a9L8L/APIr6Z827/Ro/wD0Gtiiiiio6kooqOpK8z8QKV8STeU21tgb/V/wmteK2ECL/E3O
6m/x/wB1ePl8uql0wbcu75cn/vqiK0lV13RbmjFF7o6X277Uzr/Ev7ysHUNCuo9rbnlb+7/drK+xBfvL+9prRmP5m+ZWPyr9aYtwY9rN8u01r6bqJg27pX6fdSteW
9Mk6/faL+JfMX5atLdvAny/NuG7/erK1DWn2SKrIqyYX/arn5dUl3/K371SfvVU852nVvnZf9r+KpVuJZNu1nVlH3k/i/2aFZ/ljVflYVYt7K6bduXa38TNJ93NbO
jyXFtuZm+Xhd1dppVwbm1XzW+b/wBCrQ2n9Kz9VXcm7a/y/N/wGuE1CRG1VvK/hA/4FXqujwrbaNZQr91Yl/8AQatVJRRUdFSUUVHUled+LY0tvEjSM26JoA23/a3
PW02fIVv7w/nVS4Xy4G/Gqqwz71a4/wB75K19Pt0XbtX/AGWb+9Wh9mH8XzVXuIR/3zWBqUMTJt/iXLM396ubntINjMvk/MfveZ96suW3K7tzJ8orS0+0Rn+XY3P/A
D0+7XR2+j+YnzLuVsfNVXUtNlg3fNu3A/8AAcVympKV2/3ud1ZiqW27V3Vdt4Xk+X+LP3a6nT/Dm7a3lJ838X92tiLR4o9y7f8Avv71Ma3Lbdv3l/vfxUyXTn/eMsr
t5n8NWNNmMG2Nl/df3v8AgP8AFXSKwbdVXUFLWjbWTcoNeeLCY9djgiZGZZ49u/8AibdXrsWVSPd97A3VNRRUdFFSUUUVHzv3buw+WuE+ItvJvt7iKLdkeXu/77ral
X5FZfdaz5f7vz1B5yfvGXe3O356cuu2un/eb5VxWbe/ECCB/wB1buy/9dKy7rxjrU9o1yunPFBz+98tttZv/CTXU7tHuRmb7u+mLqkrf63Yq/d+atO1ZLncsS/LgfN9
K09PthY3yrKz7cHbXbrIip8uysXUr1N+35Onzbq4zxBsaeRol+9n5qyrWyeR1X+981dNprWdim6XZ/47tWrcviqzj+6rsqmoW8XJPtVVRvMJXb5lQf8ACQj7V5jWj
r/7KtXLXxHayTqzfKuP++q29qMkbKvy4+WtKykH3fenXHzQSfQtXnmnsk+s2jbtzfaY9qt/vV63/dpKkooqOipKKKKZLII4Gkb+GuK8YXjXelCOe32rncrf3flrQb/j0
Vv++qoXC/uJJG+7j5q5jWr+Vd0duu5mJ2t8u3isOK0uJ763jume387/AJay/wANdXqXhm30PTY73T1e4njlDM38TLWTdeLtRuYPI+0J5Ej/ADK0f3lP8NT6PDb65dTS
agqRWtpEFj2fw1Qi0fU13TWkT3Vqp+Vk+8qiur8P6LbyWMNzu/2tqVNqGyC6h2/981at5H2LIy/M3ystVdQUtO38K4Py/wDAf7tcndWxg1KH/nllFrUaweRNsX3sBlX+6
v8AeasHUm3XX2TTLd7j7OP3jJH97Fa17o+neHPsdzqyPq7SIfl/5ZRt/D8tU9X1HRNQmWODRobWCM+ZuSP5m/2flqK30eLUEvZtP3r5ZHlr/rFrIlWe2nkjuN8Usfy7q2
tH1+W2RYLj5ov9v7tdxpVx58CyL8v8LVtXWPsszf7BrkvA+l/ab5r2VXaOM7l3f3tz16LRRRRUdSUUVHRVXVbQ3umzWyvskYfK30rgbK/fVdKa21NfKvIR8y/+zV1NxlU
X+Km+SGgamW9lFG7Sbfvf99VE1lBPO32iJKlt9lsiqv8Aql+X5v4a5u90vw557N5TrPnc0UO7/wBBpixwKm1Ynt4FPy7v4f8AgP3q0NNsop0aOJX8pgN2yT5WxWldSQaf
a+XEzxKo2r/s1kL5tzfeZu+6AtaW7/a/3lqrLIjP/s1U1KyE6bvk/vKz1Qiu92mtHu+bn/pmq4q/pVlFaWknlS3X77G5V/hzRqH2Wex+yXrO391m+9trnP7Hi8+Pyr5GX
IVtn3q6ayU2yfZNPbyosDczbada6BYtdST3W+WVhuZm/vVQl8MwRvuiX733a2vD9l9hTy2/3a3L1Q2m3St93yn+/wD7tcjpsN15FutvdzW65HmRJ/kV3OlSFrXbu3eXhd
zVcooqSio6kooopjf6tq8i0Rri+1Wa52v8qeXuau9ul3fxURN8m3+H7tWG+Z6b5Yk+981V2tH/ANiopbK4+XayK33fkquuko0/mXDPLtx977taDSD/AFcS/drHuI3V22/N
0+5UUsiWm1m+Xj/vqoluH3x7vm3H+L+9/wABqWLP2pfv/MQu2rTKNkfy/MoNZrWnlz7l+aJgd391atWv+jOu7/VMv3mq3cWUVzt/2sfd/irFl0I/dZUbj73+rpy2Ev7vcz
7Vy1atlD5D/K33vvVd2/PuqaJf4ttXJV3QSL/eQ1wOsasbSxVl/wBb92NX/vD+79K7nwor/wDCKadJL/rZoEkb/eK1r0VJUdFFSUUVHUlcbqFolokltaLt8xw0n+1V/UPu
L/FUUTfd/h3VdX/ZWpfvf+zUcLTWY/wrTGjMn+9Q0aRwNWLL825dyLtNZVwvmT7mb+DbWha2EvkR+U3zY+9/s1L9k2v/AB9lq3FGdi7vvLn5qY0e5KZ5Y2bafbs6/K33f7
1DTCTarLtp/wB7cy7PmH3ql2/d/wC+W2U7+NfpVhYwyfd+WpZV/cN9DXA+K1tb7wvYalpku5bSfa2z/bb5v/Hq9D0SMweH9Phb70dtGrf981doooooooooqSsfUI0kn3bf
mWq90paBfuVFF99v4f8Aeq1Fj/vqrG4U371G2nUyVd33vu1z2qyBXaNd+5jTLWEtdbt3y4Hzf3q6qKMRp81V72Pcny1EuF+WqVxmP7q+u2ofODbtrIy5+b+9U3Dbf4uR96
jy0Xd8vysPmpnH/Ac/NT1b+L/PNSq27+H/AIFVqL/ZqVvuVxem2D/8THSJf9V9ph+VfeXdXo6rt2r/AHRtpKKKKKKKKKkorldakMGpRyeb97C7f71WLpf3C7l+ZTVeJhvX
cydfvVaWQ/wruqVW/wDHv4asf+PU2pfvVDL9xv4VrAW0SeeSa6+b5yyq392ori4ia6WCJvmx95albWJY9u75V4Zt1RXHiHcnyrt/2qzZdWlg3XP2jdE33tn/ALL/APrq1o
+vxXKeXcfe/hq7dLFBdrIv3ZB/BViJgz/K27n/AL5qX+P/AMeprNu/3V/vVCyhvut81Kuf4vm/9Bq+rfw7v++qsfwfN92s/RY/P1W4mb2b/wCJrpKKKKKKKKKKKkrl9dkE
bs0sW5VG5afFMJ9Njb+Fk3VVaQK/zN8v8NSrIP4tm2rUTfJ/Buare77tJu3VN/BVe4+WBv8AarzvWtfntkkgXerKfu/8CrlLVdYadZoldv4Wrf1LUfM/d+b82R/y0+7VLz
i0Ei/61cH722qusXFxcpDbRf6qP+FP71Urf7RBu+ba33VruNEke5tVWVvlX5V3f7v8NdFFJudfmRf71S/eT7v3v+mdN3De21aYzHf91P8AaoaQsm1v+BbqsRNt/wBnrV24
U/YZlX73lPUXheMrBuZXVsbWVq3qKKKKKKKKKKKyNd06a78uS1+8pG5arrGV01VaLyto+7/drNuPlRt33VO6nxM6/wB/5flq1FIf97+7VtWOz5acrf3WqZpKqXEw2Mq1yu
saAl88kkX7pm+arGj6FBp6N5v+kN/eqXVdF0y7tGjiVIpc/erD/wCEOeNF3Xf/ANlTG0WCT5V/dLwu7/LU218L+XOsksu7aN0f92tq3t9u7b93/wBlq/Ev3f8AllT1+58y
9j8tMb5UVWV23GopW3bV27f9qm+cPP27fXbV+Jt25f4v9qruoSGPTbpvu7Yj81S+H98lq1zLLu8zFa9FFFFFFFFFFFFU9SX7rVzt0o3/ADKnmr93d71VVtu7zdn+0qVPbz
RKi/N977v41dVgr7asbt33aezbv/ZapN/FuqvLMFRvmfav3v8AZqq12nzKrIv+5WfLd+fPHH7j9K0NQu/kVt27cNq1mLcD7d83yt/D/vVpRfM+3du3AbtlWNu3738JqxtP
8LVE2NjKy7eKiuGG9tu/dVRvln8z5933fm/hobLT/LvrTt4yvy7e9a8tp9rtJLbdtVhtartrbJaWiwRfdWp6KKKKKKKKKKKKgvYxJatu/h+aubus72Vf/wBqqO4Sfd/h+W
T/AGqIm+78vlKvy7qtxSbf4u1WuV+b+7Q2Nm7+7VK4uBHu+b5s1SWO+1J1+zrtikI+Zv8Avr71adv4cs40b7Qz3DMd1MuNFt96+Uzqqmqv2SBd3ms7f7lQ/ZrVdzRSurNl
dtRbXg+b5FViPmq6sx3qu19q/wANWIm/yn8K07htu3ZUVxhflX5lWqTb2fa3zNT/ACfkXcu5l/76/wD2a0rVdv8AD90Vv2v3N1WqKKKKKKKKKKKKKay7kZW/iFYF1jeyt8
u2sWVjv3L93JZqZ/e+b73973qVfl+VflZjWhuEaL81V5WMny/e2/8ATT1qJlg37r2VGZQFVau2+qIqeWv3vurRcaokHl7m+VjRb3HmJ8retZ9xepHP97/9moLi/DfNtSV
V+bdVdtRGzauyJvvfNJT4r23kSRf9VKtQremPdt9RHt8z/wAeraWT5Ny7P+AUSyBk+9VX+P5vm61at12/wuy1dt127tvv81dBEu1FWnU6iiiiiiiiiiiiisjWFEc6tt+WT+K
sC6X51VpX3ZP3KpNIP+Ar93f7VYXDOq7trN81StcbYGZWSsPUNRECSN/F/EtYen3F/qGpfKryysf+BLmtmXRdWnnZWZFVafceHtWa1X5kl242slZrSarbIrbX+bKtsqgzX0k
7KsU3zU6WHU/3kaq+371V9t8u1WWZeC3/AAKoPtbrOrbvmrX0+/lZ41l/4DXQ2V6disuzvurQlkdvm/hzu+eq+5F3f7X7zdV+3y237nfdsrV0+Pz32/w/eatqinU2nUUUU2n
UUUUUUVBew/abVlX7yg7a5W4Usnzep3NWK0m1Gkbe0uflqxattf5l+Zc/cqu1wdkjRN907m2f+y0+3x58c7fMqkfe963LdbOS6jkVUilX/wAerVt2iZ2VvvVd3RbKqy2lnJt
ZlRWb5aJbSzX5lVNyjbuqv5duu77m3NVZVt5EZV2NuH8Fcxe2GnW19JcqqNP97a33WzWNcYW6jZV9P0q9as/nqsu/5vu/7P8A3zWm0m3zPK2bv4f/AGaofORtv+zlfnrYt22
wfeRdo2/NXSaVCYIGZt7NJ83zVdooop1FFNop1FFFFFFFc9rtuFdmXZtkB/76rk723P8AE23aPm/d0K23b83yyf7tRSt87bvJ/wBmnecnzL97pub+9VeW4eOfzIm+6S3yVq2
uv/J5dx8sq/K1aS67FIn+tRl/2P71PbUbVX3eany4qve6xbqjSLKjfL92sXUNaRtvlN8qg/8AAqptrTqm2Jnqq128iMzL+9z/ABRr3pm7c+5WTa3y/wC822rEUw37tqNwf+A
rWjul2NtbauP4PZqfar+//veZ/DXSaZbG5nXd8sSj95/tZrp6KKKdTadRTaKdRRRRRRRWRrDDz41/hYHdXO3UJ+b+Ld8tZcreRubdtVqpSsVdlbf+7xuX+7UUskreY3mv82N
27/dqBpD9kZd3+9/s1ntlf4vlb7y1XaSdvl3O3Sq/nXH8XzLTfMlbb/tf+O05Wf8Aiqa33yf391Wlbb/u/wAWyrG4qjR7vu/+hVYiY/eXftX7v7v7tair/seirV+yj+8qrtl
U/NXX6PNZ/ZPskEu6SH5ZF/i3VpUUUUUU6iim8b6dRRRRRTZWdYGaJd0ir8q/3qfu/vVi6lMk7rt+ZVytZVxlk3L/AOOVi3sZX5WVGXBb5v4apSxlt0krPu5/76qJowv+1z9
2m/Zvkbd8v8Kt/dqe30sM/wA33V+6396r66BFsXd97FNl0Wwjg2yy7WX5v+BVl3Gl2/zfvU+X71Z8ulovmKsvp8v+1UH2KWP+58oNSrD5abvN71KqhkXb/Fhtr1dt8K/737v
G6rkUjyPt+Tdzt31sabbiN1bbuZvvfhWPp+o7fE96u75vtMjLXo1vMJ03LViiiiinUU2jmnVJUdFFFFZ2q3G2Bo1bbwd1YUU32m0Vl+bcTT2/h/h/9mrK1BfkX+Ff/QazZcK
nmfIvNMZv4f733f8AeqVWiWCSRW3Lk7qFuNsG7+JfmWntrX93Z027apS6oW+bzUlVht3eXUX20/6tvl/2qbcTBtu3YrZP93/x2hpom27tm5fvK9ObG/5f4fu/7K1E0m1927bu/ib7
rLT4syT7vuxKu3/ZrRt4/nVfvLkN/wACFdFZZX5mb/gVedWUm26urld+5p5P/Qq9P0e7LIvzfdB+9XQK25Plp1FFFOooptOoooooqCeby9y/xVyviK42wSMzdizVQ8LzfadChkb7r
E7q1dvyLuqGWMbNrL+6b71ZF7bOqSNEz9D8v8Lf7NYzSOz7l+9nayt95flqJrgKkm35lyN341D9rdn+8i8/89Kq3E3yfx9d3zVV85/4v/2qcsm12ZlRv+2lS/aCr7lbt/wJqeszq7
bl+bFS/az8rbvmzu2/NQuJ925vK4/76rVijKoqyruZfm/2av2X7tI9yurN96tfd5drcTNv/dxFq860pvnX+LcT+tdxa3Zg2szeq119lcBtv92tKiijdRRTqKKKKKKVm2/NWPcSf+P
V554wvS07W25/mzWr4MXb4Xt/4V+9W5xsVW/76oZfn+7tqrKoZGVt6q39azbrTomfav8AED830rAvbDyLVmVty53SbPvVis38Lb9tV2kPy7f4qbuP3fpRu2v81CybvmX/AIDTl376
t2tuWf5vl/u1tWtsWRv++mb+61XIlOxlX/VN95f7tWrdir/7K7FX/Z/3qsarMbbw/ezL/ChVfxridKjOxd2zbjbXSLM6zq3yKuP4K6nSpB+72/LuG7bXRW8nybasUUUUUUU6iim0M
wVNzVSaYyJu/hrNvZDHAzf3R81eW+KLjddLJ/FJnc1dX4Pwvhu1/usm75/et9f4dzVL9522rUDRld21vlX/AL6qo38S7UqLy9yL8yMv8X7v71Zsthbz/NL/AKpSY6oar4egW0W
S0/dN/wAtF/2a5PyS3+7QsO7b9yr8VkGRvl3LmtCKML/f6DctaMUab1ba+7nctNlZNkcm7dztp0XzOqr8rKNrN/D96tJVCv8ANs3MPvJt+asnxRMW0q4VtjMuF/8AHqyNHXd5e7f8
2d3/AHzW35Zk/ef8BrotNkKuq/xN/DXS27fJuq6rbkp1FFFFFOoptG4VSuJCz/LUUrBYFXbWbesPIb/a+WvKvFC7b5dvzfOW/wDQK7PwopXQrVW+9sFb8SlU3fxVL/Gu1vlqKVUZP
mZF5G3/AGqpXUb71/h/2v71N3Dfu83cymqksg2bvkbn7yf5/rUXmPGiq2+WJvvVzMqhn3bfu/3v8/eqpuG9V/iqwuG3NKz/AO6n8XzVdiY/6z7u3+L+LmrDMV+6vzKDtpyxld3zbV
X+593/AGqsbh8sar6/cpzKVeRf7pG7/arG8RMWsfLbf8x+Xd7VFpUYby9yo3+9/u10LL8jbvm3At/vfw1d0dRv/g3fd3eZ96unt/lTbV9amVhRQtO3UUUUU1pBH96qTXG77q0RSbv
mqGXDf7q1QuvvzfiteZeM/wB3rK/N8uP4P71dN4U/5BVuv3fkT/0Guki+58v/AHzT2UfLTN3ybv7tV5W+fbt+Vhu3VSlhdfm/5ZL/ABJ/DVVmK7f4uPvVm3Vx5fzfw4+9WHLcS+ez
Kvzcf+g1X8w71+b5m/vVKqiN9v3f9qrcTBd21f3v8X+7WguF+98zZ+7/AHc07du3fK+1fvfvP/Qanix8qxe3/Af7tMlZF3eb/wB8/wAW6ue8QSfdWtjSrYRwLIu/purW2jZGzfMv9
2tXTF2ou1vu/wAL1r2rH7vz/wDAqu8/xU9vmTdQsn+1T/MK/wC7UqyBqfuoqi1+W+WKL/gVRJe3Uj/vVRV4+7Rz96m7f71OX5d31pvLfw/NVK6zsZtvzV5544hl8+OZl+Zidrf98V
r+GpP9Ejj+f5QGrp1y3ysv/fVS7v8AKVFuPy/+yUyX5v7/AFNV5VMaK21Opqq0Y3tJt8rd/D/erKvYfL+791vlrGuLcN96Ldx8uz+9VdYSu3+FmP8A3zT1j/1a/e2n/gNTqo/2F4q
3/tNv3fwr/e/z9al5+6u/p/49QzBtvyv8ufmXdTJW8vczK67T97/7GuevW8+eH5flz/F/vV12nqFgjXdu/wByr6w7kZm/dLj5q0rWE7G2qityyq1Ytv4ss2uljaXyufmby/lrrLXU
Uk8tW/5afdZPu1prUTLt+VvutRzSKu77rbamViv+7Uu6sdV+fctPaR2/9mWhZN3+zUvHyt/EtP3f7VV2bdu+b5ar3CjY23/vlv4q57xRYG50aRfK+Zgdq/3WFYHhe4KvtZU/3mrto
vm+7T9259rb9tM8wsis38Xy/wC781MlUf3fvZ3VFt3O38Srn/8Aaqvu3Jtb+HNUrqP5F+X7pH3P4qybiP5I/wB6m1vu/wC1UUtuI/l+7u+7UPG9t3qG3VYiVNitF6/L/wAs6N3yM3y
My/w1YZdvy/3vvf7NRKw37V3r5f3m/i21Xupvk/urztrN02PzNZj3K+2P5mrvbW2Pyr/CuP8AgVXfLLPt/wCBbf8AaqLWr0aZoV1N/EqFY/8AaYr8teZW8PmPtX7zEfN/eru/C8yLYrb
XC/Z7pvmjZvuy4rXstR23zWzK9u3/ACz3/dl/3a34pBco395fvU2KT5Pm+9ipd3+1QrU/dWb5h2baZu+T5vajzP7vytirC42bfuqtG4/wtUX/AAF6Yy/P81Yuu4Xy1+euUlj/ALP1VWV
f3FwSy7P4a6vT5tyK25KsNIPmaL0H60MwVP8AW/8AAU/ipjSBflVvm5+X+7TFYq7bm3Lk/wDAaguF8v5t
33j97zPL25qlcNudW2urfxf7NUJZPuwrvZs7m/z/APXqk0gj3fLt3H5v9qomkO/d97cRUtv+8fayuu771WGYqkfzbdv9aiZSqbV/iP3Wpm4xorfOu0bvyqrdNu2rt27f+mn3q1PC9
gfmudv+sPy7vau2t/ufd+XG1f8Ad/2asSsF+98u37tch44m8z/iXr/y7kMzf3mK1zNlaFv3n/Aq6u1jLWLWjLubAZVb+9VJoZ5EaO4a62qdu3zPu11llduqM3zyyrlm/wBpa0L2Sa
Pbc2ipL/z03SUz7W6p+9t32/7FTW9wkjsqt82Pu/xVaXOz5q//2Q== ]';
begin
insert into t ( c1 ) values ( replace( vstr , chr(13) , '' )  ) ;
commit;
end;
/

SQL> @insert.sql

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select count(*) from t ;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1

SQL> select length(c1) from t ;

LENGTH(C1)
----------
     13691

SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
```